# Lost access to grub after installation of Peppermint 4

Tags: partition, grub, dual-boot

I have installed peppermint 4 but after restarting it, the grub menu didn't show up and now it boots straight into Windows. I went back into peppermint by using "Try out Peppermint" option from the boot USB. I've also run

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and this is the output.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd9aacbf3

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 2048 821247 409600 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2 821248 489330687 244254720 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3 489330688 976773119 243721216 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x99954f66

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 2048 557340671 278669312 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2 * 557340672 557828095 243712 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3 557830142 691828735 66999297 5 Extended
/dev/sdb5 557830144 567828479 4999168 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6 567830528 667828223 49998848 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7 667830272 691828735 11999232 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 16.2 GB, 16231956480 bytes
140 heads, 32 sectors/track, 7076 cylinders, total 31703040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdc1 * 32 31703039 15851504 c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

The `/boot` partition for peppermint was set at `/dev/sdb`.

I have also tried to use type this code:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
chroot /mnt
```

It has managed to mount it but after trying `chroot /mnt` it says:

> Operation not allowed.

What can I do to enable grub now?